# Sublime Text print output for Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sublimetext3

This is kind of a silly question but I'm hoping for some insight :)

I am unable to access Ipython Notebooks at my office due to ridiculous security controls and printing out a dataframe in sublime doesn't always look very nice to me.  I was wondering if there is any sort of package or setting that can print them out in a more structured, table-like manner?

Comment: What about an [Excel spreadsheet](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)?

Comment: Thanks Matt but I'm looking to print to the build within Sublime.  Thought there might be a way to print out like an SQL style table with some package (with pluses and minuses surround borders, or something similar).

Answer (score 3):

I think [`pd.DataFrame.to_string()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) is going to be your best bet if you are only going to use Sublime and nothing else. It allows you to specify many options, including which columns to print, their minimum width, a list or dict of formatter functions for formatting each column (for example, if you want to round floats to 2 decimal places), justification of column labels, and others. I don't think it adds demarcation marks around the table or under column headers, for example, but those can easily be added later in Sublime if needed.

If you need more options, then consider using [`to_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html). The advantage of this method is that you can define arbitrary CSS classes to be applied to the table, in which you can customize formatting and presentation down to the *n*th degree. For example, you could design your table using something like the [CSS Table Generator](http://www.csstablegenerator.com/), then style the outputted HTML with it. It's not quite as straightforward as using an IPython Notebook, but I would argue it actually gives you a finer degree of control of presentation.